# allow array form validation symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation, yaml

i have an error when i want to validate this class

```
    /**
     * @SWG\Property(
     *     type="string",
     *     description="The customer's uuid",
     *     example="ffs-cse48q4s-csvdf-5sd"
     * )
     */
    public $guidCustomer;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(
     *     type="array",
     *     description="",
     *     @SWG\Items(
     *         @SWG\Property(property="guid_invitation", type="string", example="ferfrd7"
......................
     *     )
     * )
     */
    public $invitations;
```

```
App\Application\Command\Invitation\InvitationCreateCommand:
  properties:
    guidCustomer:
      - NotBlank:
          message: invitation.guid_customer.not_blank
    invitations:
      - NotBlank:
          message : invitation.invitations.not_blank
```

I am using an on-the-fly form generation system from commands. I want the validation to work for the invitation field which is a php array, I don't know what to put, I didn't find it on the doc

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the invitations array content.

If you have for instance an Invitation entity (or even a simple class), that composes the array, put your asserts on each fields, and then use the "Valid" assert (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html) on the invitations field.

However, we'd need more info about the array content, but you could put an All assert (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/All.html) on invitations, and put in a custom constraint.

I'd go with an Invitation subclass if you don't have one, it doesn't need to be an entity.